# strange problem with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I downloaded the latest version of cakephp. I use cake command line tool for creating a sample project. However, I edited the view file with corresponding controller file but the edited content does not appear. I try a test by rename the view folder of application but the view displayed normally. I think that the view I edited is not the true view cakephp use for rendering. 
P/S: the view folder is under the application folder. 
-- Edited 
The file I edited is: C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\myapp\views\posts\index.ctp 
And the link I was trying to view is http://localhost/cakephp/myapp/posts/index . The edited content does not appear. I also tried an absurd test by deleting the view folder but the webpage display normally. I really don't understand what happened.

Comment: add the file path of the file you edited and the path of what you're trying to view pls

Comment: @Dave: I just clarify the problem

Comment: I think that when I use scaffold in cakephp, the view generated in the view folder wasn't used but the view generated by cake engine. Therefore when I delete the var scaffold, the view need to be constructed from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to construct the view again when you delete the var scaffold.

Make a index action (method) in the post controller and then your app get your index view.

[Please read the cakephp docs for further information.](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1103/Scaffolding)